# Current through two vertical ideal conductors

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Let's consider the circuit:

[image]

Do I understand correctly that current can't flow through these two vertical ideal conductors? (Voltage source and connecting conductors are assumed to be ideal (with zero resistance).)

I've just built the diagram, but it's not so:

[image]

I think this question refers to the non-trivial physical idea. I just want to understand the undefinity of currents in these loops. However, it seems that this uncertainty cannot be removed in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of those extra vertical conductors forms a loop and the current in the loop is the current in the extra conductor. There is no voltage drop anywhere on that loop and there is no resistance anywhere on the loop. So KVL is satisfied with any arbitrary amount of current going around the loop. There is nothing in the circuit diagram that constrains the loop current to be zero.

Comment: Thanks, it seems the currents in these loops can't be determine, so they are undefined. It looks like "inertial motion", but for the currents.